# Нужна помощь с тг ботом

Tags: python, telebot

нужно сделать программу для тг бота на telebot для решения простых примеров. Например
вводишь в чат 10-5 одним сообщением, как боту понять какие 2 числа в примере и какую с ними операцию сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Получаешь текст от пользователя и кидаешь его в функцию eval

Answer (score -1):

Он получит данные либо из константы, либо из базы данных по команде. Откуда укажите.
Вот вам пример:

```
x=1
y=2 
z = x + y
```